# How can I display error messages for individual form inputs using semantic-ui?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-hook-form

I've been messing with semantic-ui for a while and came across this [Field Error](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#states-field-error) section in the documentation. The code looks like this:

```
  <Form.Input
    error={{ content: 'Please enter your first name', pointing: 'below' }}
    fluid
    label='First name'
    placeholder='First name'
    id='form-input-first-name'
  />
```

The result is a error state, where the input field turns red and a message appears. But the documentation doesn't quite show how to implement this behaviour, if you just put this error prop inside the component it'll just stay permanently red.

I am currently using react-hook-form for validation and to display error. My input fields look like this:

```
        <Form.Field>
            <Form.Input
                label="Name"
                placeholder="Enter the cat's name" type="text"
                {...register("name", { required: true, minLength: 2, maxLength: 30 })}
            />
            <p>
                {errors.name?.type === "required" && "You need to write the cat's name"}
            </p>
        </Form.Field>
```

It would look really nice to display that kind of behaviour (all red with error messages when the user attempt to submit with an empty field) but I just can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding a prop `error={errors.name?.type === "required" && "You need to write the cat's name"}` to your `Form.Input`. Looking at the documentation a simple string will work.

Comment: It worked!
I've thought I tried this before but I think I've put an extra pair of brackets.